# How to solve this limit question with sqrt

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{x \to 2^-} \sqrt{2-x}
$$
I know the solutions is = 0 (defined when $x \le 2$) but how ? can someone please explain to me

Comment: Uhm... No, that's not true. $\lim_{x\to 2^-}\sqrt2-x=\sqrt2-2$. Or, according to the other interpretation, $\lim_{x\to 2}-(\sqrt2-x)=2-\sqrt2$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path OP wants $\sqrt{2-x}$...

Comment: i know that every limit when x gose to 0 and we have sqrt(-x) something negativ that the solution is undefined but in my case its 2- , dose it mean just put 2 in x and we get sqrt(0) ?

Comment: What properties for $\lim$ do you know?  Are you looking for an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think about $x \to 2^-$ as $x = 2-y$ with $y \to 0^+$, so you get
$$
\lim_{x \to 2^-} \sqrt{2-x}
 = \lim_{y \to 0^+} \sqrt{2-(2-y)}
 = \lim_{y \to 0^+} \sqrt{y}
 = 0.
$$

Comment: thats hard to understand, why should i think about x = 2-y, how should i know that

Comment: @WTF Idea of changing variables for simplification is to approach $0^+$ in your one-sided limit. So $x \to a^+$ can be thought of as $x=a+y$ with $y \to 0^+$, and $x\to a^-$ can be either thought of as $x=a+z$ with $z \to 0^-$ or as $x-y$ with $y \to 0^+$...